# trying to move between fragments with bottom navigation view _Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to make a nav bar and move between fragments
I use this method to move between fragments:

```
private fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.flcontainer,fragment)
        addToBackStack(null)
        commit()
    }
```

and here I'm tryin to set the nave bar on Listener:

```
        val fragmenthome = Home_Page_Fragment()
        val fragmentaccount = Account_Page_fragment()
        val fragmentwallet = wallet_page_fragment()
        val fragappointment = Appointment_Page_Fragment()
        NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.mihome -> setFragment(fragmenthome)
                R.id.miappointment -> setFragment(fragappointment)
                R.id.miwallet -> setFragment(fragmentwallet)
                R.id.miaccount -> setFragment(fragmentaccount)
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

now my program will only show the HomeFragment and it wont move to other fragments

here is my menu file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mihome"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
        android:title="home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miwallet"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_account_balance_wallet_24"
        android:title="wallet" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miaccount"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_account_circle_24"
        android:title="account" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miappointment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_calendar_month_24"
        android:title="appointment" />
</menu>
```

I tried to move between fragments with nav bar but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Jetpack navigation component to new setup BottomNavigationView.

Here's how you can set it up:

1. Create a nav_graph and add all your four fragments as destination. You don't need to create directions betweem them since they'll be connected via bottom navigation.
2. Add `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` in the Activity that host your host fragment and set set menu items. Your code will look something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_bar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

3. Inside the `activity.kt` add the below code in the `onCreate()` to setup AppBarConfiguration that accepts setOf fragments in the BottomNavigationBar.

```
 val navController = findNavController(
    R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main //Id of the host fragment
 )
 appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(
        R.id.FragmentHome, //These are the ids from nav_graph for each fragment
        R.id.FragmentAccount, 
        R.id.FragmentWallet, 
        R.id. FragAppointment
    ))
 setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

You can use this video for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chso6xrJ6aU&list=PLSrm9z4zp4mHilvsfUM3jeCYFV3fTAS3J&index=4

Hope it helps!